# Twilio TwiML app XML error

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api

I have a TwiML app with this code in the Connect action of the CallController. This code is taken straight from the Twilio demos.

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Connect(string phoneNumber, string called)
{
    var response = new VoiceResponse();

    var dial = new Dial(callerId: "+6138595????");
    if (phoneNumber != null)
    {
        dial.Number(phoneNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        dial.Client("support_agent");
    }
    response.Dial(dial);

    return TwiML(response);
}
```

When this is called it raises the error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

The XML this generates is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="+6138595????">
    <Client>support_agent</Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Evangelist here.

A quick question - is this happening every time the method is invoked, or only when specific inputs are provided? Needing to build the string manually is of course not desired. So I would like to get to the bottom of what triggered this result.

Comment: Every time, I have found a work around but it is possibly a bug in the Twilio library.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that @Craig. By default, `return TwiML(response)` will set the encoding of the response to [Encoding.Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netframework-4.7.1). I think Encoding.Default is giving you some issues here. You can override that by specifying `return TwiML(response, new UTF8Encoding())` instead. Based on the [code in GitHub](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-aspnet/blob/master/src/Twilio.AspNet.Mvc/TwilioController.cs), that will end up doing the same as your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have found I can fix it by replacing

```
return TwiML(response);
```

with

```
return new TwiMLResult(response.ToString(), new UTF8Encoding());
```

Appears to be some kind of encoding issue using the first method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem we solved it in our WebApi by skipping the Twilio sdk and generating the xml by ourselves.

I hope this will work for you too:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual HttpResponseMessage Connect(string phoneNumber, string called)
{
            string twiml = $"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Response><Dial callerId=\"{phoneNumber}\"><Client>support_agent</Client></Dial></Response>";
            var xmlResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
            xmlResponse.Content = new StringContent(twiml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

            return xmlResponse;
}
```

Please notice that there are no end of lines - "\n", \r", etc.